How to make shadcn table scrollable?
I encountered a problem. On official shadcn site, table is a scrollable on a small screens:
Shadcn site
I added table in my project, and on small screen i dont have scroll-bar, and all my layout shifts:
My site
My code:
import { ScrollArea } from "@/components/ui/scroll-area";
import {
  Table,
  TableBody,
  TableCaption,
  TableCell,
  TableFooter,
  TableHead,
  TableHeader,
  TableRow,
} from "@/components/ui/table";

const invoices = [
  {
    invoice: "INV001",
    paymentStatus: "Paid",
    totalAmount: "$250.00",
    paymentMethod: "Credit Card",
  },
  {
    invoice: "INV002",
    paymentStatus: "Pending",
    totalAmount: "$150.00",
    paymentMethod: "PayPal",
  },
  {
    invoice: "INV003",
    paymentStatus: "Unpaid",
    totalAmount: "$350.00",
    paymentMethod: "Bank Transfer",
  },
  {
    invoice: "INV004",
    paymentStatus: "Paid",
    totalAmount: "$450.00",
    paymentMethod: "Credit Card",
  },
  {
    invoice: "INV005",
    paymentStatus: "Paid",
    totalAmount: "$550.00",
    paymentMethod: "PayPal",
  },
  {
    invoice: "INV006",
    paymentStatus: "Pending",
    totalAmount: "$200.00",
    paymentMethod: "Bank Transfer",
  },
  {
    invoice: "INV007",
    paymentStatus: "Unpaid",
    totalAmount: "$300.00",
    paymentMethod: "Credit Card",
  },
];

const HospitalTable: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <ScrollArea>
      <Table className="text-xl">
        <TableHeader>
          <TableRow>
            <TableHead className="w-[100px]">Invoice</TableHead>
            <TableHead>Status</TableHead>
            <TableHead>Method</TableHead>
            <TableHead className="text-right">Amount</TableHead>
          </TableRow>
        </TableHeader>
        <TableBody>
          {invoices.map((invoice) => (
            <TableRow
              key={invoice.invoice}
              className="text-black dark:text-white"
            >
              <TableCell className="font-medium">{invoice.invoice}</TableCell>
              <TableCell>{invoice.paymentStatus}</TableCell>
              <TableCell>{invoice.paymentMethod}</TableCell>
              <TableCell className="text-right">
                {invoice.totalAmount}
              </TableCell>
            </TableRow>
          ))}
        </TableBody>
        <TableFooter>
          <TableRow>
            <TableCell colSpan={3}>Total</TableCell>
            <TableCell className="text-right">$2,500.00</TableCell>
          </TableRow>
        </TableFooter>
      </Table>
    </ScrollArea>
  );
};

export default HospitalTable;


Please help me to fix this.
I want to make the table doesn't shift my layout, and it will be responsive with scroll-bar

Looks like the default behaviour of the table is to allow the cells to shrink as small as possible until being scrollable. Are you sure your table is at that point? In the screenshot it looks like all of your content can fit in each cell. If you don't want the cells words to jump onto new lines, you can add td { white-space: nowrap } in a stylesheet somewhere.

The dimension of table isn't small enough to the scroll appears. Select a cellphone dimension and check if it changes.
